# CheckBoxList check all items on click working only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have checkBoxList contains number of months and I need all items in this list checked when user click check all I have this HTML:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbAllYears" Text="All Years" runat="server" />


   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblstMonthAvailability" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Jan" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Feb" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Mar" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Apr" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="May" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Jun" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Jul" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Aug" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Sep" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Oct" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Nov" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Dec" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and this is my Jquery code its working only on first click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cbAllYears").bind("click", function () {
                $("INPUT[id^='cblstMonthAvailability']").attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `CheckBoxList` is a server side control, the name attribute will be be changed along with Id's. One way is to add a class as suggested by @Alex. Also, you can find all the checkbox inside the table which is rendered by CheckBoxList like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#cbAllYears").click(function () {
       $('input[type="checkbox"]', $("#cblstMonthAvailability")).prop("checked",$(this).prop("checked"));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to add a class to `checkbox` elements and using jquery like:

```js
$("#cbAllYears").on("click", function() {
  $(".month").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbAllYears" text="All Years" runat="server" />All
<input type="checkbox" Text="Jan" Value="1" class="month" />Jan
<input type="checkbox" Text="Feb" Value="2" class="month" />Feb
<input type="checkbox" Text="Mar" Value="3" class="month" />Mar
<input type="checkbox" Text="Apr" Value="4" class="month" />Apr
<input type="checkbox" Text="May" Value="5" class="month" />May
<input type="checkbox" Text="Jun" Value="6" class="month" />Jun
<input type="checkbox" Text="Jul" Value="7" class="month" />Jul
<input type="checkbox" Text="Aug" Value="8" class="month" />Aug
<input type="checkbox" Text="Sep" Value="9" class="month" />Sep
<input type="checkbox" Text="Oct" Value="10" class="month" />Oct
<input type="checkbox" Text="Nov" Value="12" class="month" />Nov
<input type="checkbox" Text="Dec" Value="12" class="month" />Dec
```

Comment: Im using check box list and I can`t add class for checkBoxList Elements

Comment: @MohammedAlasa'ad - You can with `CssClass` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('[id$=cbAllYears"]').change(function (e) {
       $("input[id^='cblstMonthAvailability']").attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
       return false
     });
 });
```

Comment: Please do not post "try this followed by a bunch of code" answers. Add a few words/sentences to explain what exactly is the problem and how your solution fixes it